# What does the error "Cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.QueryTriggerAction'" mean?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coding a game in unity and I got these errors

> Cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.QueryTriggerAction' 
>  Argument 3 may not be passed with the 'out' keyword

I don't know what these mean. If you can help, it will be appreciated! 
Here is the relevant code

```
  public GameObject mainCamera;
    RaycastHit hit;
    public LayerMask DestrObj;
    public float reach;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) & Physics.Raycast(transform.position, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, DestrObj, reach))
        {
            Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It means you have a type conflict.

Comment: It means exactly what it is saying: you are providing a `float` where a `UnityEngine.QueryTriggerAction` was expected ... in general you want to use `&&` logical and instead of the `&` bitwise operator!

Comment: I have used this exact on a different device and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters provided to `Physics.Raycast` are invalid. Regarding the the error, you received, the fifth parameter that the method expected was of type `QueryTriggerInteraction` but the one that was provided was a `float`.

Here's a reference regarding the `Physics.Raycast`.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html